# a format specification for argument 2, as in 'msgstr[0]', doesn't exist in 'msgid_plural'

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, translation, poedit

I have the following code:

```
public function bulk_updated_messages ( $bulk_messages = array(), $bulk_counts = array() ) {

    $bulk_messages[ $this->post_type ] = array(
        'updated'   => sprintf( _n( '%1$s %2$s updated.', '%1$s %3$s updated.', $bulk_counts['updated'], 'yosilose' ), $bulk_counts['updated'], $this->single, $this->plural ),
        'locked'    => sprintf( _n( '%1$s %2$s not updated, somebody is editing it.', '%1$s %3$s not updated, somebody is editing them.', $bulk_counts['locked'], 'yosilose' ), $bulk_counts['locked'], $this->single, $this->plural ),
        'deleted'   => sprintf( _n( '%1$s %2$s permanently deleted.', '%1$s %3$s permanently deleted.', $bulk_counts['deleted'], 'yosilose' ), $bulk_counts['deleted'], $this->single, $this->plural ),
        'trashed'   => sprintf( _n( '%1$s %2$s moved to the Trash.', '%1$s %3$s moved to the Trash.', $bulk_counts['trashed'], 'yosilose' ), $bulk_counts['trashed'], $this->single, $this->plural ),
        'untrashed' => sprintf( _n( '%1$s %2$s restored from the Trash.', '%1$s %3$s restored from the Trash.', $bulk_counts['untrashed'], 'yosilose' ), $bulk_counts['untrashed'], $this->single, $this->plural ),
    );

    return $bulk_messages;
}
```

And then in my .po file I have:

```
#, php-format
msgid "%1$s %2$s updated."
msgid_plural "%1$s %3$s updated."
msgstr[0] "%1$s %2$s actualizado/a."
msgstr[1] "%1$s %3$s actualizados/as."
```

But when I try to create my .mo file with Poedit, I get this error:

```
a format specification for argument 2, as in 'msgstr[0]', doesn't exist in 'msgid_plural'
```

I don't get what's wrong here. Is it the way I call "_n", or something in my translated string?

I see that is somehow related to the sprintf position markers... that poedit apparently doesn't like that I have $3%s in msgid_plurals and not in msgid... but shouldn't just translate the string "as is"? I'll pass the translated strings to sprintf at runtime, inserting the appropriate nouns in place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not that Poedit doesn’t like it, it’s gettext `msgfmt` tool — and your way of doing plurals fails its sanity checks. As you observed, the reason is that you must use the *same* arguments in both `msgid` and `msgid_plural`. Just do it.

If you’re wondering why, it’s because your code ignores the possibility that some languages may have more (or less!) than just two forms, singular and plural. Slavic languages have 3, Arabic has 6, Japanese just 1. Your code could never work right with these languages.

As is often the case, the GNU gettext manual discusses this issue in some detail:
http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html

Comment: Trying to make things dynamic and wrapping my head about this... :P 

Do you think something like this would be a proper way to accomplish what I want?

 'updated'   => sprintf( _n( '%1$s %2$s updated.', '%1$s %2$s updated.', $bulk_counts['updated'], 'yosilose' ), $bulk_counts['updated'], _n($this->single, $this->plural, $bulk_counts['updated'] )  ),

I tested it and it works, I'm only worried it's not the proper or best way to do it... Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Well, comment formatting is messed up. But if it works I could update my question or edit your answer for future seekers.

Comment: @yivi Do read the linked manual section, it explains what the proper thing to do is and why. Your mistake is in using `%2$s` as a placeholder for a proper word in the first place — that can’t word well and even if you manage something somewhat working, your translators will hate your guts (and will make made translations).

Comment: @yivi Also, it is *never* a good idea to pass anything other than *string literals* as `_n`’s (or any other gettext function’s) string arguments. Never, ever do that. It makes the actual strings inextractable. You really should read the manual, it explains all these things in detail — and well.

Comment: Yes, I read the docs you linked, thanks. Again, I'm probably just not understanding it well. My apologies. I get now that passing anything else but literals to gettext functions is not a good idea. My train of thought was that since $2%s was going to be replaced with another call to _n(), with the same number as quantifier as the first _n() call; the translation would have worked (and future translators wouldn't have hated my guts).

Comment: Normally this should work. I had this kind of error when I accidentally changed %d to %s in the translation.